# Query is outputting more rows than it should do

Tags: php, mysql, database

Below is my query:

```
$query = "
          SELECT gr.SessionId, t.TeacherUsername, s.ModuleId, m.ModuleName, 
      st.CourseId, st.Year, st.StudentUsername, gr.Mark, gr.Grade
      FROM Teacher t
          INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
          JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
          JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId
          JOIN Course c ON st.CourseId = c.CourseId
          JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
          JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
          WHERE
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
          ";
```

Below is what is query is outputting:

```
Session ID  TeacherUsername Module Number   ModuleName  Course ID   Year    Student Username    Mark    Grade
AAA            m.prigmore   CHT2520        Web Program  INFO102      1      u1231231            69       B
AAA            m.prigmore   CHT2520        Database     INFO102      1      u1231231            69       B
AAA            m.prigmore   CHT2520        Web Program  INFO102      2      u0833421            71       A
AAA            m.prigmore   CHT2520        Database     INFO102      2      u0833421            71       A
```

If you look carefully what is happening is that in the Course_Module table which I have used to JOIN the Course table and Module table, there are 2 modules for the course 'INFO102'. Because of this it is showing 4 rows as it is trying to show two Modules Names (which comes from module table) for a Session for each student. This is incorrect as it should only link to the module which belongs to the session which should be 'Web Program', not 'Database' (This is because ModuleNumber CHT2520 = 'Web Program' in Module Table).

Below is what it should output:

```
Session ID  TeacherUsername Module Number   ModuleName  Course ID   Year    Student Username    Mark    Grade
    AAA            m.prigmore   CHT2520        Web Program  INFO102      1      u1231231            69       B
    AAA            m.prigmore   CHT2520        Web Program  INFO102      2      u0833421            71       A
```

So how can I get rid of the rows which says 'Database' under 'ModuleName'  and that Module Number only matches with the correct Module Name?

Thank You

Comment: What happens when you JOIN on ModuleName, and then use ModuleName as a criteria in your WHERE clause:

Comment: I have just tried this and what will happen is that it will show 2 rows. But if nothing is entered it will go back to 4 rows even though it should stay as 2 rows

Comment: Can you run a query outputting all records in Module where ModuleNumber is CHT2520?  From the looks of it, this appears to be a data problem.  Please double-check.  I assume that ModuleNumber and ModuleName both come from the Module table.

Comment: I will run the query but I have changed the SELECT to the fields I want to choose from, so the Module Number is actually coming from the Session table as it is a foriegn key used to link to Module table and the ModuleName comes from the Module Table

Comment: I run the query you told me to do and there is no problems, It shows 4 individual modules and their correct module names, so no data problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting ModuleNumber from the Session table and ModuleName from the Module table.  Your query says, "for this session, get all grade reports, and for those grade reports, get all students, and for all students, get all courses, and for all courses, get all course-module links, and for all course-module links, get all modules."

That's why you see all modules listed for that combination of grade report, student, course and module.  You could add "AND s.ModuleId = m.ModuleId" and that should fix it.  I presume you have ModuleId in the session table, if you also have ModuleNumber.  And if so, you don't need ModuleNumber in your Session table.

Comment: Module Number is ModuleId in the database table but I will try what you have just said. Give me 2 minutes

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you, I did try m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId but it didn't work but then when I did it the other way round which you mentioned it worked. So I have learned that it should be first JOIN table and key that = Second JOIN table and key.

Comment: Hm the order shouldn't matter, if you mean "AND m.ModuleId=s.ModuleId" versus "AND s.ModuleId=m.ModuleId".  At least as far as I know.

Comment: I actually included it as the first part or the WHERE clause and then AND 'next condition', no matter it works and I have learned something new, thank you

Comment: The ordering of the AND elements won't matter, but since he is also using an OR statement, it is important the the OR be one component of the AND.

Comment: @Mayur Patel - if dnuttle's answer resolved your issue, you should mark his answer as the correct one, and possibly upvote as well. That is what makes Stack Overfolw work  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ModuleID as part of your WHERE statement. I am not fluent with MySQL, so to avoid butchering this I will use pseudo-SQL:

```
WHERE 
    ((gr.SessionID = '' OR gr.SessionID = $SessionID)
AND
    (cm.ModuleID = $ModuleID))
```

Note that the OR condition needs to be one component of a greater AND specification.

In other words, you need to differentiate the two modules in your criteria.

Of course, this assumes that the Module named "Web Program" is unique and has a different ModuleID than the one named "Database". However, the fact that they each share a "Module Number" in your result set concerns me. If they do not have unique and different ID's in your Modules table, you will need to either JOIN on the "ModuleName" field, or (and perhaps more importantly) make sure that modules are uniquely defined within your data model.

If two modules with different names, and which represent different criteria choices are represented by a single record in your table, you have a fundamental design problem.

Anyway, here is my attempt to put your MySQL query together. Again, I have probably muffed the syntax. Seems like a lot of extra punctuation in there . . . ;-)

```
$query = " 
      SELECT * 
      FROM Teacher t 
      INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId 
      JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId 
      JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId 
      JOIN Course c ON st.CourseId = c.CourseId 
      JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId 
      JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId 
      WHERE 
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' 
      OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid))."'
      AND cm.ModuleID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."') 
      ";
```

Hope that helps.